# Azure Policies to limit the scaling of database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-policy

When a new SQL database is created on Azure, it sets "Compute+Storage" option to "2 vCore + 32GB data max size" as a default configuration but I don't want to use vCore and I can change it. But the question is that if it is possible to limit the subscription with a policy to not let any user be able to create a database with undesired size. Is there any way to limit the scaling of the database?

Comment: Hi @Developist,  If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vCore model General Purpose is the default price tier of Azure SQL database. We can't change the default configuration but we can manually change it to DTU model manually after it created like you said.

About your question "Is it possible to limit the subscription with a policy to not let any user be able to create a database with undesired size?", the policy is that only the server admin account can change and create database.

Azure database support auto scale up according your data increasing and database price tier. It's the feature and we can't disable it. When you design your database, you need think about the max size of the database. When the limit arrived, you need to choose the higher price tier. In one word, there isn't a way to limit the scaling of the database.

HTH.

Comment: Hi @leon-yue thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Developist It‘s my pleasure! Have a nice day!